# Import issue in SudsLibrary in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, suds

I am trying to import SudsLibrary for my Robot Framework testing. I have downloaded the zip file from the location https://github.com/ombre42/robotframework-sudslibrary and have extracted the jar and kept it in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages where my python2.7.15 is installed, even tried putting in the folder of my workspace. But the moment I write Settings and try to import the library, I get error. Quickfix is also not solving. Here are some screenshots. Any help on this, will be great.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q8pR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try this:

```
pip install robotframework-sudslibrary
```

this should work perfectly fine. And, if you are working on Linux machine and sometimes,you make get permission error then go for this

```
sudo pip install robotframework-sudslibrary
```

Comment: Is there any version we need to give while installing??